# Inequality on polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, inequalities, enumerative-combinatorics

Recall $[n]_q=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}, [n]!_q=[1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q$ and the Gaussian polynomial $\binom{a}{b}_q=\frac{[a]!_q}{[b]!_q[a-b]!_q}$ with $[0]!_q:=1$.

Given two polynomials $U(q)=\sum_k\alpha_kq^k$ and $V(q)=\sum_k\beta_kq^k$, we write $U(q)\geq V(q)$ provided that $\alpha_k\geq\beta_k$ for all $k$.

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Suppose $\binom{A}B_q\geq\binom{a}b_q, \binom{D}E_q\geq\binom{d}e_q$ and $\binom{A}B_q\binom{D}E_q, \binom{a}b_q\binom{d}e_q$ are two polynomials of equal degree, hence $\binom{A}B_q\binom{D}E_q-\binom{a}b_q\binom{d}e_q\geq0$. Also suppose the ratios
> $$\frac{\binom{A}B_q}{\binom{d}e_q} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\binom{a}b_q}{\binom{D}E_q}$$
> are actually polynomials in $q$. **Is it true that the polynomial**
> $$\frac{\binom{A}B_q\binom{D}E_q-\binom{a}b_q\binom{d}e_q}{\binom{D}E_q\binom{d}e_q}\geq0\,?$$

Comment: Have you found many such quadruples fulfilling the conditions already? Are they hard to find?

Comment: I have plenty such.

Comment: I have just kept my computer busy for somme hours by doing a nearly exhaustive search for any pair of rows below 50 in Pascal's triangle. First I thought that all such polynomials are (up to some isolated powers on either end) unimodal, hoping that this might give a hint towards a proof, until I came to rows 46 and 23 with (B, b)=(5, 6) and (E,e)=(2, 3) where the unimodality is "slightly violated" at many places. Looking at the lowest order terms of both quotients for some feasible pairs, the numerical evidence for the positivity seems overwhelming, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wolfgang.